# Tkinter - post all pairs of images per two of a folder in the same display, side by side

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Tkinter - post all pairs of images per two of a directory in the same display, side by side

I would like one loop inside another, in order to use Tkinter, to post all the images inside a folders (png), including all the possible pairs of them! e.g. If 10 images exist under a specific folder, i would like 
to display (10!) 100 pairs of images (i dont mind some double ones).

my code until this time is:

```
<pre>
import os, sys
    import random
    import numpy as np
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from Tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import tkFont

    path1='/'
    dirlist=os.listdir(path1)
    ln=len(dirlist)

    #counters
    ln
    size_im=5
    ii=0


    for ii in range(0,2):
       root1=Tk()
       j=ii+1
       dl1=dirlist[0+j]
       image1 = Image.open(os.path.join(path1,dl1))
       image1 = image1.resize((image1.size[0]/size_im,image1.size[1]/size_im), Image.ANTIALIAS)
       display1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
       label1 = Label(root1, image=display1)
       label1.pack()
       for kk in range(0,2):
          root2=Tk()
          m=kk+1
          dl2=dirlist[0+m]
          image2 = Image.open(os.path.join(path1,dl2))
          image2 = image2.resize((image2.size[0]/size_im,image2.size[1]/size_im), Image.ANTIALIAS)
          display2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
          label2 = Label(root2, image=display2)
          label2.pack()
          root1.mainloop()
          root2.mainloop()

#ultimately, i would like something the below one in photo pairs

for ii in range(0,5):
    j=ii+1
    dl1=0+j
    for kk in range(0,5):
        m=kk+1
        dl2=0+m
        print [dl1, dl2]
<code>
```

Comment: You can only have a single instance of `Tk` in your application. If you need to open additional windows you must use instances of `Tk`. I don't know if that's the only problem, but it's certainly the biggest.

Comment: Start by reading all of the images into a list of images.  Then, loop through the list (for image in list_of_images:) and create a Label for that image.  Grid http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm this label in column=0, change the column to 1 for the next label.  Every time the column==1, change it back to 0 and add one to the row to move down.

Comment: Do you want all the images to show at once, or only two at a time?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, it is python code that can display multiple images 
into the same canva, multiple images side by side, multiple images one under another, all images into one directory / folder. To display all possible pairs of images: for example: if only 3 images exist in the same folder, their pairs that will be displayed will be the following ones: 1-1,1-2,1-3,2-1,2-2,2-3,3-1,3-2,3-3. you may adjust counters.

I made the path in such way, to be adjustable. nothing more.
The main idea was to enter the two loops one under the other as well to use the same label (label1) for both images under one root/main loop.

```
        <pre>
    # importing
    import os
    import sys
    import random
    import numpy as np
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from Tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import tkFont
    # the path that must contain supported (only) image formats
    path1 = '/'
    dirlist = os.listdir(path1)

    # to find the number of images under the directory
    ln = len(dirlist)

    # counters
    # the number of images under the directory
    ln
    sm = 5
    ii = 0
    # making two loops, with main function inside of these loops
    # two counters for two files,directories (here, the same one)
    for ii in range(0, len - 1):
        for kk in range(0, len - 1):
                # open the main loop
                root1 = Tk()
                # increasing one unit each time the loop is repeated
                j = ii + 1
                dl1 = dirlist[0 + j]  # in each loop, next image is loaded
                # joining the path with image filename
                im1 = Image.open(os.path.join(path1, dl1))
                im1 = image1.resize(im1.size[0] / sm, im1.size[1] / sm)
                # ready to display image in tk
                display1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
                # labelling image is very essential
                label1 = Label(root1, im=display1)
                label1.pack()
                # second counter for the same directory, file
                # to make the second pair
                m = kk + 1
                dl2 = dirlist[0 + m]
                # second image from the same directory is loaded
                im2 = Image.open(os.path.join(path1, dl2))
                im2 = image2.resize(im2.size[0] / sm, im2.size[1] / sm)
                # ready to display
                display2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
                # load it to the same label pack, in order
                # to be displayed in the same canvas
                label1 = Label(root1, image=display2)
                label1.pack()
                # closing the main loop
                root1.mainloop()
                # all possible pairs of two images inside
                # a directory will be displayed one next to other
                # If you have lets sya 10 images then 10*10=100
                # canvas with two images each will be diplayed
<code>
```

Comment: Did you try running this code? I think you'll find it doesn't work even remotely like you expect.  You've created 25 infinite loops,  running sequentially.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, added more comments and checked it against pep 8 austere guidelines.